# proxy with rewrite including headers

Tags: proxy, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to proxy a wordpress site to a subdirectory of another site.

So, I have a wordpress site articles.blah.com/subdir/. It writes html with absolute paths like http://articles.blah.com/subdir/page1/.  It also does http headers with absolute redirects like location: http://articles.blah.com/subdir/account.  Its already in the apptly named subdirectory "subdir".

I need to proxy it to the main site under the subdirectory. So, I'm looking for a proxy solution that will be able to perform a rewrite on the http content including the headers.  So, http://www.blah.com/subdir/* would get proxied to http://articles.blah.com/surbdir/*.

I've tried to do it on the wordpress host which already has nginx with the subs module but that only rewrites the body - any redirect header gets left alone so the redirects would fail.

What would the easiest way to do this be?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is the `proxy_redirect` directive to rewrite the `Location` header when it appears.